# How to get which process is using the directory?

Tags: windows, process, resources

I want to remove all files in the directory `d:\\tmpdata` in os `win10`.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('d:\\tmpdata')
```

It encounter an issue such as:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'd:\\tmpdata'
```

Try to get which process is using the resources--directroy `d:\\tmpdata`:

```
tasklist  | findstr  'tmpdata'
```

or

```
tasklist #run it only ,search by eye.
```

No process can be found ,how to get which process is using the directory ?

Comment: [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try built-in software Resource Monitor. Search resmon.exe. Start program, select CPU then Associated Handles - type your folder path and see, what is using it.